# PDO Works for all but not in Cron Yii2

Tags: pdo, yii, cron, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on Yii2 advanced app and I have created cron job for my need but same code inside cron works in application but not works in console cron controller.

It gives error like 'Class PDO not found'.

```
namespace console\controllers;

use yii\console\Controller;

class CronsController extends Controller {

public function actionIndex($id = null) {
    if(isset($id)){
            $command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO table (user) VALUES (:user)");
            foreach($gets as $row){
                $command->bindValue(':user', $row['user']);
                $command->execute();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you setup the db component in console/config/main.php?

Comment: How to do that? inside console/config/ ?

Comment: Yes, there should be a components section in the main.php file. In there you will need to specify the db component and its settings.

Comment: You can find information about those settings here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html

Answer (score 0):

first step command run

> php -m | grep PDO

To see if it exists,if not exists PDO, you need install PDO extension

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Comment: PDO is exist there